# Is meta reserved name for Blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have quite strange situation.

I use:

```
@include('partials.meta')
```

If the file does not exists I got error, but if it exists no content from partial is added.

But if I only change filename from `meta.blade.php` to `metatags.blade.php` and change include into:

```
@include('partials.metatags')
```

the content of the partial is added.

Is somehow `meta` as name causing any conflict in Blade?

Comment: I just created meta.blade.php in my partials and its works perfectly. Think issue is from your side.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the same thing also, and it worked without any issue. Maybe in your meta.blade.php file you have @section('meta'), but that only works when you have a @yield('meta') which you want to populate with the meta.blade.php contents. However if you are using @include in the area you are going to use the contents, there is no need to use @section, so remove that and everything should be fine.